# C# MemoryStream Write method writing all 0's to byte array

Tags: c#

I am trying to decompress a file using the GZipStream class. I use the GZipStream's CopyTo method to write the decompressed data to a MemoryStream object. After copying to the MemoryStream object, I can see the data is there by looking at the _buffer in the non-public properties.

The problems begin when I try to write to a byte array. Making the call to the Write() method results an a byte array full of 0's, as well as the _buffer property going to all 0's. I thought it might be a position or flush()/close() problem, but that does not solve it. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
var input = new MemoryStream(data);
var output = new MemoryStream();

using (var x = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(input, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    x.CopyTo(output);
}

output.Position = 0;
var bytes = new byte[output.Length];

output.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //All 0's 
output.Flush();
output.Close(); //still all 0's
```

Comment: What does `var bytes = output.ToArray();` give you?

Comment: you don't think that `data` might have something to do with the question?

Comment: You realise that `output.Write` actually writes data **into** your memory stream? You're doing it back to front here.

Comment: Try... var bytes = output.ToArray();

Comment: Sorry, don't you want to Read, not Write?

Comment: Are you sure you want to set the output Position to 0 after writing the data into that stream?  What is output.Length after that?  Seems like you are writing the output data twice.

Comment: Ack! I did want Read(). How embarrassing. Thanks for getting me back on the right path guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Read` not `Write` to get the data out.

```
output.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

You also could do

```
var bytes = output.ToArray();
```